# Парсинг сайта animevost

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер

Не могу разобраться как мне вытащить из `div` тег `a` и и спарсить другие пагинатции

мой код

```
 import requests
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 
 url = "https://animevost.org/"
 response = requests.get(url) 
 soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml') 
 quotes = soup.find_all('div', class_='shortstoryHead') 

 print(quotes)
```

сайт https://animevost.org/

Comment: Скажу вам по секрету "div" тоже тег.

Comment: и я тебе раскрою свой секрет я знаю

Comment: "как мне вытащить из div тег a" soup.find('div', class_='shortstoryHead').find('a')

Comment: quotes = (x.find('a') for x in soup.find_all('div', class_='shortstoryHead'))

Comment: спасибо за помощь